# Issue with Java Maven project during Tomcat startup. Bean creation of a Repository class failed because the Entity referred is not a managed Type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa

I have a Java Maven project configured to use Spring framework. It also uses JPA / Hibernate to perform DB interactions. My back-end DB is Postgres.

I initially had my project access one Postgres DB. I had defined the DataSource, EntitiyManagerFactory and TransactionManager in beans.xml file.  I then needed to enhance my project to also interact with a second Postgres DB. As a result I updated my beans.xml to now configure a second set of DataSource, EntitiyManagerFactory and TransactionManager for the 2 DBs (see configurations below referred as "label"). I made the original configurations corresponding to the first DB as the primary one

```
   <jpa:repositories base-package="com.aaa.bbb"/>

<!-- Configure the entity manager factory beans -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="fhirDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aaa.bbb.model.*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="labelEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="labelDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aaa.bbb.label.model.*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the data source beans -->
<bean id="fhirDataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" primary="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9001/fhirdb"/>

    <property name="username" value="fhirserver" />
    <property name="password" value="change-password" />
</bean>

 <bean id="labelDataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9002/labeldb"/>

    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="labeldbpwd" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" primary="true">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="labelTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="labelEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Now when I start my Tomcat server it fails with the following message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'establishmentRepository' defined in com.aaa.bbb.splfhirpoc.establishment.EstablishmentRepository defined in : Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.aaa.bbb.label.model.EstablishmentEntity
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at <unknown class>.getObject(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

Also, every time I start my Tomcat, the error points to failure related to creation of a different Bean. These beans being referred in the error message can be mapped to Entities / Repository for any of the 2 DB. For example, this is the error I got when I started the Tomcat server second time. The Bean referred in the first error referred to the Repository class created for the second DB (label) while the second error I reported corresponds to the Beans created for Repostiory / Entity for the first DB

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventRepository' defined in com.aaa.bbb.splfhirpoc.audit.AuditEventRepository defined in : Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.aaa.bbb.model.AuditEventEntity
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at <unknown class>.getObject(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

Here are examples of a Repository class and Entity I have implemented

**EstablishmentEntity.java**

```
package com.aaa.bbb.label.model;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.aaa.bbb.splfhirpoc.common.SplFhirpocDataException;

@Entity (name = "establishmententity")
@Table(name = "ESTABLISHMENT", schema = "label")
public class EstablishmentEntity implements Serializable  {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(EstablishmentEntity.class.getName());
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//@Column(name="id", updatable = false)
@Column(name="ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String id;

@Column(name="REGISTRANT_ID")
private String registrant_id;

@Column(name="CONFIDENTIAL_FLAG")
private String confidential_flag;

@Column(name="GDUFA_ESTABLISHMENT_FLAG")
private String gdufa_establishment_flag;
```

**EstablishmentRepository.java**

```
package com.aaa.bbb.splfhirpoc.establishment;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.aaa.bbb.label.model.EstablishmentEntity;

@Repository
@Transactional(timeout = 600, value = "labelTransactionManager")
@EntityScan("com.aaa.bbb.label.model.*")
public interface EstablishmentRepository extends JpaRepository<EstablishmentEntity, Long> {
    

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select a.*, d.\"DATE\" "
        + "from \"label\".\"ESTABLISHMENT\" a, \"label\".\"SUBMISSION_ESTABLISHMENT\" b, \"label\".\"SUBMISSION_STATUS\" d "
        + "where a.\"ID\" = b.\"ESTABLISHMENT_ID\" "
        + "and b.\"SUBMISSION_ID\" = d.\"SUBMISSION_ID\" "
        + "and d.\"CODE\" =  'Received' "
        + "and a.\"DUNS_NUMBER\" = :duns_number "
        + "and d.\"DATE\" = (select max(e.\"DATE\") FROM \"label\".\"SUBMISSION_STATUS\" e, \"label\".\"SUBMISSION_ESTABLISHMENT\" f "
        + "WHERE e.\"SUBMISSION_ID\" = f.\"SUBMISSION_ID\" "
        + "AND f.\"ESTABLISHMENT_ID\" = a.\"ID\" "
        + "AND e.\"CODE\" = 'Received' ")
List<EstablishmentEntity> getAllEstablishmentsByDuns(@Param("duns_number") String duns_number);
```

It definitely looks like there is an issue with how Spring ingests its code based on Annotations and every time I start my Tomcat server, one of the Bean referred using Autowire fails causing the error I am reporting. How can I resolve this issue? Am I doing anything wrong ? Any help to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: Looks like the entities are not getting scanned... Try this i.e. @EntityScan("com.aaa.bbb.label.model") or even @EntityScan("com.aaa.bbb.label.*")

Comment: In **EstablishmentEntity.java** the id is of type **String** and in **EstablishmentRepository.java** where it says **extends JpaRepository<EstablishmentEntity, Long>** you have a **Long**. They should both be either Long or String. Might not be the fix but just something to note.

Comment: I was under impression that: 1. `@EntityScan` must be placed on a `@Configuration` class 2.  `@EntityScan` dees not accept globbing patterns. 3. `packagesToScan` does not accept globbing patterns. I would try adding correct packages to `packagesToScan`.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.I was able to resolve my issue my modifying my packageToScan to com.aaa.bbb.* for primary datasource and com.aaa.bbb.label.* for the second DB. I also made one more change to the beans.xml configuration. I renamed the primary DB related configuration to the default values (like dataSource, entityManagerFactory and transactionManager) and kept the second DB configuration details as is. I am not sure if one of the 2 changes resolved my issue or both the changes were required to resolve.